# Is it impossible to simulate this hairstyle?

Tags: animation, particles, photorealism, filmic-blender

I want to create a hairstyle like the one in this image using particle hair, and then simulate and animate it.
[image]
However, how do I create and simulate the part where the hair is tied up? I can fake it in a still image, but in a simulation, it seems difficult.

Comment: if you don't succeed with hair dynamics maybe try with Cloth simulation? Create a cage to which you give a Cloth simulation, give your hair a Mesh Deform modifier?

Comment: As moonboots said, if you're not planning on simulating any high frequency details like little strands of hair moving independently, a Mesh Deform modifier is the way to go, it's much faster as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to simulate it with a ***Mesh Deform*** modifier:

Create a cube that will be the *Mesh Deform* cage and that contains the hair, create a vertex group where the cube is supposed to be attached to the head, give a *Cloth* physic to the cube with the vertex group as *Pin Group*, parent the cube to the head. Parent the hair to the head, give the hair a *Mesh Deform* modifier with the cube as *Object*, click on *Bind*. Give a *Collision* physic to the head:

[image]

Comment: After researching it, I understood it. Thanks to everyone who commented.